# Gradle Command-Line Arguments for tests in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle

I'd like to pass an argument to Gradle test (override some property in application.properties).

There is a way to pass an argument when bootRun is executed. Check e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments:

./gradlew bootRun -Pargs=--some.property=changedvalue

But I want to do it in tests, something like:

./gradlew test -Pargs=--some.property=changedvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. I propagate command line arguments to system properties.

```
test {
    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        project.args.split(',').each {
            def (key, value) = it.replaceFirst('--', "").split('=')
            systemProperty ((String)key, (String)value)
        }
    }
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And following command line works fine.

```
./gradlew test -Pargs=--some.property=changedvalue
```

Comment: @SpringBootTest(args = "...") not recognized by Gradle, I have to specify "jvmArgs ..." in build.gradle, hmmm.